# Http response status in headers or in content

Tags: ajax, web-services, http, xmlhttprequest

I have to write an application which serves `HTTP request`.
For these requests application has to send the response content with status**.
Status is integer which represents status code.( 1 : Session Expired, 2: Invalid Request Data. etc,.)

There are 2 options.

One is to send the status code with content itself:

Ex : `{status : 56, content: [{name:'pinto', id: 90}]}`

Another one is specifying the status code in header itself, so that once I receive the header from client if status states the there is an error I can abort the request so that I don't have to receive the response body and process it.

I think second option will be better than first one, because 
No need to get for the response content which is very much helpful in case of content is large.

Is this is recommended solution or any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [HTTP status codes](http://httpstatus.es/) for this kind of thing.

1. Session Expired: [401 Unauthorized](http://httpstatus.es/401) - authentication is possible but has failed
2. Invalid Request Data:

   - [400 Bad Request](http://httpstatus.es/400) - request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax
   - [405 Method Not Allowed](http://httpstatus.es/405) - request method not supported by that resource
   - [409 Conflict](http://httpstatus.es/409) - request could not be processed because of conflict
   - [413 Request Entity Too Large](http://httpstatus.es/413) - request is larger than the server is willing or able to process
   - [422 Unprocessable Entity](http://httpstatus.es/422) - request unable to be followed due to semantic errors

Comment: If we have custom status(other than HTTP standard statuses) how would we handle in this case. For example if user name is not there I want to return some status code which is different for invalid password, again this is just an example. I can have large set of constants.